# Extract Image from JSON file (php)

Tags: php, json

my JSON file created from SUMMERNOTE form contain html and image, as I see the Image within JSON enclosed with in `<img` tag, so I do `strtok()` to Retrieve `<img>` TAG from within JSON file, like so

```
    <?php
$filename = "Artikel9.json";
$myData = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename),true);
//var_dump($myData);

$myContent = $myData[0]['content'];
//echo "Retrieved data : <br> $myContent ";

if(strpos($myContent,"<img") != false)
{
    $myImage = strtok($myContent,"<img");
    $myImage = "<img".strtok(">").">";
    echo "<br>myImage "; var_dump($myImage);
}
?>
```

and this is my JSON data;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hdFGmHAfTfH70bNZHAbIygUOxOpSzTRD/view?usp=sharing

but `var_dump()` only has `string(7)`;
can anyone explain this ?, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtok()` doesn't take the whole token as a splitting point. It uses *any* character in the token to split the string.

When you call `strtok($myContent, "<img");` it doesn't look for a string "<img" in the string, any first `<,i,m,g` character will match and get split.

You may want to use `strstr()` and `substr()` to retreive your data.